# magento configurable products options

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, production-environment

In my store i have all the products as configurable products and there is no simple products displayed on store. Everything goes fine but then i noticed one problem.

After adding a product to cart by choosing the simple product from the configurable product page, i still gets configurable products sku in the cart , also it maintains through out the session. So we cant track actually which product sell.

Is it problem with any configuration or should i do anything to catch the simple products sku instead of configurable product SKU.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit late if your store is filled with configurable products, but I've found this product a lifesaver in the past:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products

It basically just adds the simple product to the cart using the simple product's price as the buying price. Custom options must also be added to the simple products rather than the config products.

As a result the purchased item is the simple product SKU rather than the configurable product.

Comment: I am using this plugin, but is there anyway to automatically copy the parent data to all children products. Having to reenter all shipping information is a bit tedious.